# how to apply sed command on a array variable

Tags: bash, sed, sh

The primary goal is to know how to use the `sed` command on a array-variable rather then a file.

Secondary is to remove the `path` out of the array, the final output should contain only the files names

sample data:

```
path=$(pwd) 
echo $path
>> /home/peter/my_commands

array=($path/*.sh)
echo "${array[@]}"
>> /home/peter/my_commands/func1.sh /home/peter/my_commands/main.sh /home/peter/my_commands/test.sh
```

desired output: `func1.sh  main.sh  test.sh`
this values inside of array-variable called `array2`

##### summarizing:

```
#input data
array=(/home/peter/my_commands/func1.sh /home/peter/my_commands/main.sh /home/peter/my_commands/test.sh)

#sed command to make the transformation
#HERE..

#output will be
array2=(func1.sh  main.sh  test.sh)
```

##### failed attempts:

```
# sed -i -e 's.$path..'
# array2=$(sed -n '2p' $path)
# array2=(($path/*.sh) | sed -i "s.$path..")
# array2="$(echo $array | sed -i -e "s.$path..g")"
# array2=$(sed -i -e "s./.." <<< "$array")

echo "${array2[@]}"
```

Comment: let me edit the question @GillesQuenot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ array=(/home/peter/my_commands/func1.sh /home/peter/my_commands/main.sh /home/peter/my_commands/test.sh)
$ array2=( "${array[@]##*/}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array2[@]}"
func1.sh
main.sh
test.sh
```

Using bash *parameter expansion*